# Tailwind extend with custom scss file in Angular 9

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I have Tailwind working in my Angular 9 project, but I'm having trouble customising it with style rules in another file.

Here is my tailwind.scss file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@import "styles/buttons"; // doesn't work
@tailwind utilities;
```

And in _buttons.scss in the styles directory:

```
.btn {
  @apply bg-red-600;
}
```

But this style is not picked up.

If I do this inline it works i.e.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
.btn {
  @apply bg-red-600; // this works
}
@tailwind utilities;
```

But it would be great to have seperate files for managing this.

Comment: I think the trick is to not use @tailwind for base, comp and utils, but to simply do a normal import on them..

Comment: Do you mean something like @import "node_modules/tailwindcss/dist/base.css" ? That doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Okay - that did it for me.. but maybe my setup is different.. scss anyway..

Comment: Apologies Mike you are correct, I had the path wrong. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion by @MikeOne, I changed the import to the following which worked:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "./styles/custom.css";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

I also setup the style preprocessor path in my angular.json file:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
   "includePaths": [
      "./node_modules"
   ]
}
```